# Executing .exe file from java application

Tags: java, c, exe

I wrote a C program that simply delete the folder called myFolder.txt
I want to execute the .exe file from a java application.
So, I used the following code:

```
 try
 {
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime() ;
    Process p = rt.exec("program2.exe") ;
     p.destroy() ;
 }catch(Exception exc){/*handle exception*/
System.out.println("ERROR");
    }
```

When I run my java application no error appears but the file is not deleted.

Why?

Comment: No the C program work well. it test if there is a txt file with the name Myfolder.txt ,, if yes it removes it
I tried to run the .exe from a command line and every thing is ok

Comment: 1) Why not delete the file using the J2SE File API?  2) If using `exec`, be sure to read & implement all the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html). 3) `exc.printStackTrace()` is both shorter to type and more informative at run-time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have created a process, and then immediately [destroy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy%28%29)ed it. Of course the executable won't run. Try calling [`.waitFor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) instead (or just let it run).

Answer (score 2):

I think that `program2.exe` might not be in the class path of the Java project.

```
try  {
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime() ;
    Process p = rt.exec("program2.exe") ; // @1
    //p.destroy() ; // @2
} catch (Exception exc) {
    /*handle exception*/
    System.out.println("ERROR");
}
```

@1 - check path of the exe file.

@2 - no need to destroy the process manually, it will end automatically after completing its process.

You can check whether the the process is started or not, run the Java project - immediately go to task manager - process - if there is a process running called `program2.exe`, your process is started otherwise it is not started. If not started, there is no exception - then the `exe` file path is a problem, try with giving full path of the `exe` file.